# Find the indices of values fulfilling condition in 2d numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a 2D array of values and I'd like to find the indices at which the values are more than 60% of the maximum value.  I have tried:

```
: nmax, nmin = np.amax((n[:,:])),np.amin((n[:,:]))
: np.unravel_index(n[n>0.6*nmax], n.shape)
```

But I get the error:

```
TypeError: Iterator operand 0 dtype could not be cast from dtype('>f4') to dtype('int64') according to the rule 'same_kind'
```

Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you try [numpy.where](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html#numpy.where)?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above use np.where() like this:

```
    x = np.random.randint(0,50,(20,20))
    y = np.where(x>0.6*np.max(x))
```

y will be given as a tuple with two arrays representing the two axes of the array and you can use y however you need to for example x[y] will return the values of x all of which will be greater than 0.6*max.